# Why is @angular/core/core has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'. error thrown when using angular cdk virtual scroller

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I installed CDK Virtual Scroller in my ionic 5.3.3 project:

```
npm add @angular/cdk
```

The version is:  "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.2"

The scroller viewport wraps a ion-item-group:

```
<ng-template #showContentBlock>
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
            itemSize="56"
            minBufferPx="900"
            maxBufferPx="1350"
            >
          <ion-item-group>
            
             <ion-item-sliding *cdkVirtualFor="let test of tests">
    
            <ion-item class="notification-item" lines="none" >
              <ion-avatar slot="start">
                <img src="./assets/tests/tests6.jpg">
              </ion-avatar>
              <ion-row class="notification-item-wrapper" (click)="openTestModal(test)">
    
                <!-- <ion-col size="1">
                  <app-aspect-ratio [ratio]="{w: 1, h: 1}">
                    <app-image-shell class="notification-image" src="./assets/tests/histology1.jpg" [alt]="'conatct image'"></app-image-shell>
                  </app-aspect-ratio> 
                </ion-col> -->
                  <ion-col class="details-wrapper">
                    <h2 class="details-name">{{test.investigation}}</h2>
                    <p class="details-description">{{test.Lab}}</p>
                  </ion-col>
                  <ion-col size="2" class="date-wrapper">
                    <h3 class="notification-date">{{test.SpecimanType}}</h3>
                  </ion-col> 
              </ion-row>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item-options slide="end">
              <ion-item-option color="danger" (click) = "removeTest(test.id)">
                <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
              </ion-item-option>
              <ion-item-option color="success" (click)="updateStudent(test)">
                Edit
              </ion-item-option>
            </ion-item-options>
          </ion-item-sliding>
          </ion-item-group>
        </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

The viewport css properties:

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When I build the project I get the following error:

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/cdk/bidi/directionality.d.ts:22:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"../User Manual/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

22     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Directionality, [{ optional: true; }]>;

This is versions:
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.2.3
@angular/cli                  : 10.2.3
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI      : 3.3.2
@capacitor/android : 3.3.2
@capacitor/core    : 3.3.2
@capacitor/ios     : 3.3.2

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.2
native-run                             : 1.5.0

System:

NodeJS : v14.17.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm    : 6.14.15
OS     : macOS Catalina

I have been searching on web but I don't understand the error or how I might go about further debugging it, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your angular is version 10: `@angular/cli : 10.2.3` and CDK is version 13. Get them in sync - and problems of this kind tend to go away

Comment: Ok will try and let u know outcome - how did u interpret the error message itself? I didn’t know where to start

Comment: your guess is as good as mine ;) Looks like CDK is invoking API from Angular Core that was not introduced until later